# Do Android have an activity flow similar to what iOS has with a UINavigationController?

Tags: java, android, ios, eclipse, cocoa-touch

On iOS, a UINavigationController is useful and very easy to use to push and pop views off of a stack.

Does Android have anything similar or equivalent?

Is there a recommended flow in Android, or just call Activities as you need them?

Comment: Jellybean provides some new mechanisms for more detailed manipulation of the Activity Stack, but that may be of limited use until it has a useful share of installed devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android apps maintain a stack of activities. When one activity creates another activity, the new one is pushed onto the activity stack and takes over. Read more about the stack at [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html), and more about activities generally at [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html).

Answer (score 0):

No builtin navigation control, but an activity stack is maintained by the system, and you can always go back with the hardware Back button (it's a soft button on some tablets). There's no indicator that you can go back (unless you build one), and no consistent UI for going forward. You just start the next activity.